# shuffling a word

Tags: python

How do I shuffle a word's letters randomly in python?

For example, the word "cat" might be changed into 'act', 'tac' or 'tca'.

I would like to do this *without* using built-in functions

Comment: If this is homework, as seems likely from the fact that you're apparently not willing to use `random.shuffle`, please tag it as such and *do* say exactly what you _are_ allowed to use, what you have tried unsuccessfully, etc -- fumbling in the dark trying to guess at such things is singularly unrewarding and unproductive.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want *any* random permutation of letters or *all* (unique?) permutations?

Comment: to be exact, this is what my teacher said:
The scrambling process must be implemented manually. Built-in functions or string methods that “automate” this process are prohibited from use.

Answer (score 10):

```py
import random
word = "cat"
shuffled = list(word)
random.shuffle(shuffled)
shuffled = ''.join(shuffled)
print(shuffled)
```

...or done in a different way, inspired by [Dominic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182964/3182983#3182983)...

```py
import random
shuffled = ''.join(random.sample(word, len(word)))
```

Comment: `random.shuffle` does a shuffle in place, so you don't really need to set a new variable (but you can).

Comment: thank you for the help, but is there any way to do it not using the random.shuffle ?

Comment: You could write your own shuffle algorithm, but why not use the built-in library?

Comment: I haven't done much cuz this is the only "hard"part of the lab that i was thinking about. if u want i can post my lab if you like to take a look at it?

Comment: No, that won't be needed since shuffling algorithms wouldn't be unique to the lab itself.  It's just convention on SO to post any attempts you've made at the problem you've asked about.

Comment: to be exact, this is what my teacher said: The scrambling process must be implemented manually. Built-in functions or string methods that “automate” this process are prohibited from use.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  It's extremely space and time-efficient, and easy to implement.

Answer (score 4):

```
return "".join(random.sample(word, len(word)))
```

Used like:

```
import random
word = "Pocketknife"
print("".join(random.sample(word, len(word))))

>>> teenockpkfi
```

Comment: Why are you using `letter for letter in...`? `random.sample` returns a list; you don't need to make a generator expression from the list.

Comment: yeh why are you using letter fo letter in?

Answer (score 3):

[This cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/360461-fisher-yates-shuffle/) has a simple implementation of Fisher-Yates shuffling in Python.  Of course, since you have a string argument and must return a string, you'll need a first statement (say the argument name is `s`) like `ary = list(s)`, and in the `return` statement you'll use `''.join` to put the array of characters `ary` back into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

To be very slightly more low level, this just swaps the current letter with a random letter which comes after it.

```py
from random import randint
hi = "helloworld"

def shuffle(word):
    wordlen = len(word)
    word = list(word)
    for i in range(0, wordlen - 1):
        pos = randint(i + 1, wordlen - 1)
        word[i], word[pos] = word[pos], word[i]
    word = "".join(word)
    return word

print(shuffle(hi))
```

This won't create all possible permutations with equal probability, but still might be alright for what you want

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you tweaked it so it swapped each letter with either itself or a random letter which comes after it, you suddenly have uniformity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that doesn't use `random.shuffle`. Hopefully `random.choice` is ok. You should add any restrictions to the question

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> "".join(choice(list(permutations("cat"))))
'atc'
```

This method is not as efficient as random.shuffle, so will be slow for long words

Comment: What exactly will happen if you try running `list(permutations("01234567890123456789"))`? Does it throw an exception because it runs out of memory, or just lock up your computer trying to acquire it?

Comment: @Jamie Wong, Probably takes a long time and then runs out of memory. Unless you have a 64 bit system with a bazillion bytes of RAM :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import random
def shuffle(x):
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Comment: Please *don't* use random() * n when you mean random.randrange(n)

Comment: @Marius Gedminas, but that's the way `shuffle()` is implemented in random.py ;o)

Comment: Interesting!  I wonder why?  The implementation of randrange() has a comment saying  "Note that int(istart + self.random()*width) instead would be incorrect".  Perhaps that's only for values of istart != 0?

Comment: Yes, I see now that the implementation of randrange(n) is precisely int(random() * n) when 0 < n < 2**53.